# JQueryUI animations building up while in a different tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket, jquery-animate, browser-tab

I have a real-time app where I am animating certain elements on the screen back and forth upon certain websocket-enabled events firing (e.g event "moveLeft" and event "moveRight"). When the user visits another browser tab and returns after many of these events have fired, they see the entire sequence of animation carry out (using .animate() upon each event firing) even though they are no longer relevant to the user. What I would like instead is for the animations to effectively happen while the user is tabbed away so that when they revisit the tab, they see the current world state and simply miss all those animations that were triggered while in another browser tab.

I can't seem to find any documentation on this issue; it bears similarity to the solution where you need to call .stop() before animating other mutually exclusive things so that you get don't a buildup after excessive mouseover events, but that is not really applicable here. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [slideshow goes crazy if you tab away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684330/slideshow-goes-crazy-if-you-tab-away/7685587#7685587)

In your case, since websockets trigger the animations, one solution could be to watch if the window has focus and only trigger the animations when it's in focus.